# Ajaxed page does not render jquermobile style

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The following jquery code works but it does not display with jquerymobile select form. It display plain select html. How can I make to bind the ajaxed page render jquerymobile select form.

Thanks in advance.

```
echo '<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="subject">'."\n";
echo '<label for="subjectid"><em>* </em> Subject: </label>'."\n";
if(!empty($subjectlist))
{
    echo form_dropdown('subjectid', $subjectlist,  NULL, 'id="subjectid" class="required" data-theme="c"')."<br />\n";
}
else
{
    echo "No subject registered. Contact the application administrator.";
}
echo "</div>\n\n";


echo '<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="teachernamediv">'."\n";

echo "</div>\n\n";
....
....

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#teachernamediv').hide();

    $('#subjectid').change(function(){
        $('#loader').show();
        var findteacher = "<?php echo base_url();  ?>index.php/welcome/user/findteacher";
        $.post(findteacher, {
            subjectid: $('#subjectid').val(),
            teachergrp: "5",
            user_id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
        }, function(response){
            setTimeout("finishAjax('teachername', '"+escape(response)+"')", 200);
        });
        return false;
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response){
 $('#loader').hide();
 $('#'+id+'div').html(unescape(response));
 $('#'+id+'div').fadeIn();
}
<script>
```

And this is user.php

```
function findteacher()
{
    if($_POST['subjectid'])
    {
        //$grade = $_POST['grade'];
        $subject_id = $_POST['subjectid'];
        $teachergrp = $_POST['teachergrp'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

        // check if student has a techerid in hw_user_subject with this subjectid
        $findteacher = $this->Mhomework->findSubjectTeacher($user_id, $subject_id);
        if(!empty($findteacher))
        {
            $data['teacher']=$findteacher;
            $data['header']=$this->preference->item('site_name');
        $this->load->view('common/teacher', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            // if there is no teacher then get a list of teacher names
        $data['teachers'] = $this->Mhomework->findteacher($subject_id,$teachergrp); 


        $data['header']=$this->preference->item('site_name');
        $this->load->view('common/teachers', $data);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        redirect ('welcome','refresh');
    }

}
```

This is teachers.php

```
echo '<label for="teachername"><em>* </em> Subject Teacher: </label>'."\n";
$option = array (
        ''=>'-- Select Teacher --'

        );
foreach($teachers as $row)
{
    $gender=get_gender($row['gender']);
    $option [$row['user_id']]=$gender." " . $row['last_name'];
}


echo form_dropdown('teachername', $option,  NULL, 'id="teachername" class="required" data-theme="c" ')."<br />\n";
```

Comment: Use `$( ".selector" ).selectmenu( "refresh" );` after creating select menus.

Comment: Mmm where should I place it. It doesn't work so far.

Comment: For example `$(document).on('pageshow', function() { $('#selectMenuId').selectmenu('refresh'); });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refresh the selectmenu, the html part is displaying without the runtime jquery, need to refresh it by `refresh()` in jquery mobile...

check this:- http://api.jquerymobile.com/select/#method-refresh

This is used to update the custom select to reflect the native select element's value. If the number of options in the select are different than the number of items in the custom menu, it'll rebuild the custom menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final js codes. I used combination of .selectmenu(); and .trigger('create');

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#teachernamediv').hide();

    $('#subjectid').change(function(){
        $('#loader').show();
        var findteacher = "<?php echo base_url();  ?>index.php/welcome/user/findteacher";
        $.post(findteacher, {
            subjectid: $('#subjectid').val(),
            teachergrp: "5",
            user_id: $('input[name=id]').val(),
        }, function(response){
            setTimeout("finishAjax('teachername', '"+escape(response)+"')", 200);
        });
        return false;   
    });
});

function finishAjax(id, response){
 $('#loader').hide();
 $('#'+id+'div').html(unescape(response));
 $('#'+id+'div').fadeIn();
 $('#'+id).selectmenu(); // this will refresh the select menu
 $('#myform2').trigger('create');//this will refresh the form
}


</script>
```